# Trying to use canvacord

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I used the trigger example code of canvacord, but I get the error:

```
DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message
```

My code is:

```
const Command = require("../Structures/Command.js");
const canvacord = require('canvacord');
const Discord = require("discord.js")

module.exports = new Command({
    name: "image",
    description: "Edits an image!",
    permission: "SEND_MESSAGES",

    async run(message, args, client) {

        let avatar = message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: false, format: 'png' });
        let image = await canvacord.Canvas.trigger(avatar);
        let attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment(image, "triggered.gif");
        message.channel.send(attachment);
    }
})
```

Normal text commands work totally fine, it is just this one that isnt working. I tried with other code examples, but it still doesnt work.

Comment: What's your Discord.js version?

Comment: discord.js@14.0.0-dev

Comment: let me check if it works with v13

Comment: Don't send directly the attachment, send an object with a files array property containing `'attachment://triggered.gif'` according to https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When sending attachments, you need to specify them in the `.send()` function. You need to use the `files` property to make sure that the attachment is being sent properly, so you just need to edit the way you send the attachment to:

```js
message.channel.send({
    files: [attachment]
})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).